# Touches Ended on TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I see a bunch of people asking about this on here, but I haven't seen any good solutions. Basically I want to detect when a user is done scrolling the table, and releases their finger. I don't want to do anything until their finger is off the screen or I think
scrollViewDidScroll would work. Any help would be amazing. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UITableViewDelegate conforms to the UIScrollViewDelegate protocol, which provides the scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate: method.